# File.ReadAllLines() - Reads more lines than what's in the file as null entries

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm having an issue where I have a text file as [filename].config and I use the `File.ReadAllLines()` method to read every line within it. The file only has 97 lines yet when I read it in, it has 3,973 lines stored in the string[] array. The 97 lines are all accurate but the rest after that are a bunch of null lines. I've searched online and on stack here but have seen nothing about this.

`var file = File.ReadAllLines(mainConfigFile);` is the line of code I'm using just to debug reading in the file. Just to view the values in debug mode.

Anyone have any idea of what I'm not understanding?

[image]

Comment: Does your text document have a bunch of blank lines at the end?

Comment: @Vanna You don't think it's just as likely that `File.ReadAllLines` is just broken, and no one else has come across this before?

Comment: No. Like above it only has 97 lines period.

Comment: @DanielJackson We know that's false.  There are 3,973 lines in the file, but 3876 of them are blank.

Comment: There is sensitive data within or I'd post it but in VS Code, or Notepad++, or any editor which shows lines... You can see the line count rather easily.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to read in the file? (No need to show the actual file contents.)

Comment: @DanielJackson True enough, I suppose it's possible that you're not reading the right file, that you're looking at a different array than what's returned by `ReadAllLInes`, that you're not properly checking the count of the array, or some other such thing.  I was quick to judge that you didn't make any of those mistakes, and I shouldn't have done that.

Comment: @DanielJackson we cant really help you if you dont at least post your code.

Comment: `var file = File.ReadAllLines(mainConfigFile);` That's legit the single line of code I added because I started noticing that the config file was becoming incredibly huge. I'd delete all the lines back to 97, run the application in debug, and you can see the count value of file. The file is correct as any change I make is read into the variable. I've never seen this happen so thought I'd ask.

Comment: That one line is reading in the file.

Comment: @DanielJackson So there are only three options: 1. You are reading the wrong file (meaning you have put the wrong path in `mainConfigFile`) 2. You **have** hidden new line characters in your file (or you just have tons of extra lines and you are counting wrong.  3. You have discovered a bug in .NET that you cannot reproduce because you cannot share your sample file with us.

Comment: `That one line is reading in the file.` If you write a little sample console app, which contains the minimal code necessary, does the issue exist there? If so, could you update your post with that minimal code?

Comment: I can do what you suggested @mjwills and see about figuring out myself. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Don't be too quick to delete. It's a reasonable question, but you could improve the question by providing more information that allows people to duplicate what you're seeing.

Comment: @DanielJackson - when you say it has hundreds of null lines, are they `null` literals, empty strings (`""`) or strings containing null characters (`"\0"`)? Which one it is probably goes some way to indicate what's going wrong.

Comment: @DanielJackson Like Mark asked, what are the actual values in the array that are "null".  Is it actually `null`, a blank string (`""`), is it `"\0"`?

Comment: @MarkPim Empty strings `""`. When I pass it into another method it shows `null` for the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's highly unlikely (though remotely possible) that `ReadAllLines` is broken. More likely is that what that function defines as a line break delimiter is not the same as what the programs you are viewing the file with define as line break delimiters. In the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll find this:

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage
>   return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately
>   followed by a line feed.

So, for example if your last line ended with a carriage return and 1000 line feeds, `ReadAllLines` would return blank lines (empty strings) for all those trailing line feeds. But if the program you open the file in only treats carriage return + line feeds as newlines, you wouldn't see a bunch of blank lines in it.

Note that because of the way `ReadAllLines` is written, although you can get empty strings in the results, elements in the returned array of strings will never be null. As it reads lines, it looks for a null returned from the `ReadLine` method it uses as the indication that the end of file was reached. When it gets that null, it stops reading, and doesn't add the null to the results.

A possibility is that it has nothing to do with `ReadAllLines`, but instead, there is something going on with your actual config file (and `ReadAllLines` is revealing that). Some process may be subtly adding cruft to your file. Something similar to this old [bug in the config transform](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544183/web-config-transform-writes-extra-line-break-spaces-to-values-elements-under-applicationsettings-section), or repeated round trip conversions of Windows style newlines vs. Unix style newlines while copying files, or via source control.

Comment: I will investigate further elsewhere and see how this file could be getting modified before it's being read. Thank you all the answer is very good.

Comment: @DanielJackson Most editors have an option to show all characters.  In Notepad++ its View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters.